# Brand Proliferation with Knowledge spillovers

Tags: macroeconomics, endogenous-growth, innovation

I'm studying from the Gene Grossman and Helpman textbook (1993), the brand proliferation model with knowledge spillovers (Ch.3)
I'm trying to understand the equilibrium dynamics of the model.
In this model, innovation comes from expanding input varieties, and we assume the existence of a capital knowledge ($K_n$) that increases as the number of input varieties increases:
$K_n=n$, with $n(t)$ be the number of varieties at time t.

$\dot{n} = \frac{L_n K_n}{a}$, with $a$ be a productivity parameter.

These input varieties are invented by a competitive R&D sector that uses only labor as input. The cost of a blueprint is equal to $(wa)/n$, with $w$ being the wage rate.

The free entry condition is : $\frac{wa}{n} \ge v$, with $v$ being the value of the firm. In fact, an input variety, once invented, is manufactured at a price $(1/\alpha)w$ under the following technology $x=l$, with $l$ being the labor employed in manufacturing.

The labor market clearing condition is given by:

$a \dot{n}/n + 1/\rho =L$ , with  $a \dot{n}/n$ and $1/\rho$ being the total employment in R&D and manufacturing respectively.

$v$, i.e., the value of the firm manufacturing and selling the input variety to the final good sector, with the aggregate output equal to $Y=   \left(\int_{0}^{n} x^{\alpha}(j) \; dj\right)^{1/\alpha}$, evolves as:

$\dot{v} = \rho v - \frac{1-\alpha}{n}$

with $\rho$ being the subjective discount rate, and $\pi =\frac{1-\alpha}{n} $ are the profits of the firm manufacturing the input variety.

Then, set $V= 1/(nv)$, i.e., the inverse of the economy's aggregate equity value.

Thus, the rate of innovation in the economy, i.e., $\dot{n}/n = g$ is equal to:

$g= L/a - \alpha V , for~~ V< L/(\alpha a)$    $~~~~[1]$

$g= 0, for~~ V \le L/(\alpha a)$               $~~~~~~[1]$

Then,

$\dot{V}/V =(1-\alpha)V -g - \rho$

Then, the book reports the following equilibrium dynamics:

[image]

The LL curve displays $[1]$ which must be satisfied at any point in time, and it expresses a constraint on the resources in use. The higher the rate of innovation the greater the employment in R&D and a smaller amount of labor remains in manufacturing, and so the supply of goods lowers. Lower output implies higher prices, higher wages, and a greater value of the typical firm (low $V$).
Above the VV line, the rate of reduction in the value of the firm is faster than the rate of growth of the number of varieties, and this makes $V$ go up. The opposite is true below VV.

**The book says that the graph above has been drawn to depict the case in which $L/a > \frac{\alpha \rho}{1-\alpha}$. Why? What does this condition mean?**